# Order Form - JS Alert when all the input fields values are 0

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm working on a basic ordering form. What i'm trying to achive is to get javascript to return alert when all the inputs fields are with values 0.
At least 1 of the inputs has to be filled in with value more then 0 in order to proceed with a ordering form.
I have to mention that products list / input fields are generated dynamicly so their number might vary.

Basic code:

```
<form name='packaging' action="packaging.php" method='post'>

<?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM packaging_items") or die(mysql_error());
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "
<input type='text' style='width:20px'  name='$row[prodno]' id='$row[prodno]' maxlength='4' value="0" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0';}" onfocus="if (this.value == '0') {this.value = '';}" onkeypress='validate(event)' >
";
}
?>

</form>
```

Any suggetions .. i really have no clue where to start ...

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could use the [`getElementsByTagName()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName), or [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) to get a list of all the inputs, then loop through them testing their value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code works good. All i had do is replace onSubmit="return validateForm" with onSubmit="return validateForm()" - such a little detail. Works as i wanted to. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
function validateForm(){
   var inputs =  document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   var noneZeroFound = false;
   for(var i=0;i< inputs.length;i++){
      var input = inputs[i]; 
      if(input.value != '0'){
         noneZeroFound = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   if(!noneZeroFound ){
      alert('MUST ENTER VALUE...');
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}

<form name='packaging' action="packaging.php" method='post' onSubmit="return validateForm">
```

Comment: +1. Note that if the form contains non-text inputs you'd need to test the type of each input within the loop. Also you could simplify the function my returning false directly from the `if` statement inside the loop - then you wouldn't need the `noneZeroFound` variable.

Comment: +1, one thing i would change is also `var inputs =  document.forms['packaging'].getElementsByTagName('input');`

Comment: (Sorry, I meant returning _true_ from inside the loop.)

Comment: Doesn't work. On the testing version i have 14 products and their values set to 0, so i get 14 <input type='text' name='pack01' id='pack01'> , <input type='text' name='pack02' id='pack02'> and so on...

Comment: tried with var inputs = document.forms['packaging'].getElementsByTagName('input'); - makes no diferance

Comment: Hello @Nita, there are some wrong quotation marks in php code, try this: `echo "<input type=\"text\" style=\"width:20px\"  name=\"$row[prodno]\" id=\"$row[prodno]\" maxlength=\"4\" value=\"0\" onblur=\"if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0';}\" onfocus=\"if (this.value == '0') {this.value = '';}\" onkeypress=\"validate(event)\">";`

Comment: Guys thank you. Javascript code works good. All i had do is replace onSubmit="return validateForm" with onSubmit="return validateForm()" - such a little detail. Works as i wanted to. Thanks a lot again